# Javascript Bookmarklet: fill in textfield and then click on <button>-element afterwards

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a JS Bookmarklet that fills out a textfield of a chat and then submits this with a click on the according button.

```
document.querySelector(".ember-text-area").value = "hi";
document.querySelector(".send-chat-button").click();
```

The text is being inserted successfully. But the click() doesn't seem to happen. Also doesn't execute in the JS Console in Chrome.

Interesting: if I seperate these two lines of code in two different Bookmarlets it works more or less. If I put some text in the textfield manually and then use the "click"-Bookmarklet it works. If I use a Bookmarklet to fill out the textfield I first have to click somewhere on the page or focus the textfield with my mouse manually - then the click-Bookmarklet works as well.

So I assume it has to do with the fact that the document isn't focused when I click on a bookmark-link or also when I use the console to do so. I tried different stuff like window.focus(); etc, but nothing worked. Any help appreciated!

Comment: do you want to manually click on the button or it will trigger by itself?

Comment: I want to click on the Bookmarklet and then the Button should be triggered by itself